# How to get the topmost caching in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm building a CMS. Every image would get a GUID. This means that even if user edit an image, it would be saved with a new GUID.

Thus I want to cache the image for the topmost possible cache. In fact I want to cache it forever.

ASP.NEt Core's [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0) has a long list of options.

I'm not sure what option gives me the most caching time.

What should I do to cache my images forever?

Comment: just set cache-control max-age to some big value (I believe 1 year is a max value respected by browsers)

Comment: You probably don’t want to do this unless you are using a cache-busting strategy. There isn’t actually a “forever” cache directive, but you can get close enough by specifying a very large max-age.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `memoryCache` [Caching.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/) and set `CacheItemPriority` to `NeverRemove`

**use the memoryCache in .NET Core**

1. install `Caching.Memory` from nuget.
2. in your Startup.cs file, you need to introduce MemoryCache

   ```
   services.AddMemoryCache();
   ```
3. inject to Controler

   ```
   public class myContoroler : Controller
   {
        private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache;

        public myContoroler(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
          _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }    
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm not asking about memory cache. I'm asking about HTTP caching.